BulkExtensions - how can I use a relationship property in WhereBulkContains?
I'm trying to use WhereBulkContains with a navigation property like in the code snippet below
 return this.repository.Tasks.AsNoTracking().Include(t => t.Resource)
.WhereBulkContains(resourceMappingIds, t => t.Resource.MappingId)

However, it throws
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

System.Exception: Oops! The following property names 'Resource' has not been found in the entity type 'Task'.
at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.WhereBulkContainsBuilder1.(List1 , LambdaExpression , List1 , List1 , SchemaEntityType )

If I change it to normal EF contains, the function works as expected. It looks like. Include is ignored by WhereBulkContains, what's the correct way for querying on navigation property in this situation?
I tried using ToSelfHierarchyList, however as we're later creating a lookup I require an IQueryable to be returned.
